# Why the Cookie is not changing after a while? or it returns last value?

Tags: javascript, cookies

**Cookie value's does not change after one or two changes or when refreshing the page**
it is being used to change the mode (night-light) of a website.
thanks for helping...

```
window.onload = function (){
    changeMode();
}

function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
  }
  
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
  
  function changeMode() {
    var user=getCookie("user");
    if (user != "") {
      if(user == "light"){
        dark();
        setCookie("user", "dark", 30);
      }else if(user == "dark"){
        light();
        setCookie("user", "light", 30);
      }
    } else {
       user = "light";
       if (user != "" && user != null) {
         setCookie("user", user, 30);
         light();
       }
    }
  }
```

the file:
https://kurddoblaj.com/mode.js

the Result:
https://kurddoblaj.com

Comment: When I ran your JavaScript from my server (not locally as local cookies are off) and put console.log to see the result of getCookie it changed from empty to light to dark to light to dark etc on each refresh just as you require. Are you sure the cookies are not being set property and that the problem isn't in your light/dark functions (what do they do)?

Comment: I have now tried your site, it appears to be working (sun changes to moon and vice versa). Is there still a problem? Note if you are setting cookies on a site which is seen in Europe you need to tell the user and ask for their acceptance - see info on GDPR and the EU.

Comment: Sure, I will the users for their acceptance later after running the project but the project is for Iraq-Kurdistan but they need as well thanks for the advice, I am sure the code is working perfectly for 3 or 4 times after that I think some glitches are being there.  Is that chrome problem? or my bad?

Comment: I think you may have a timing problem, I can get it to malfunction if I refresh (press enter in browser bar) very quickly but it's fine for a lot of goes if I wait a couple of seconds (using Edge, basically same as Chrome) Can you put the code where you move from moon to sun in your answer - is it purely by CSS? OR it's when the user clicks enter on the window (rather than refreshes by enter on browser address bar).

Comment: @AHaworth you are true I tested it with another browser it does not have this timing problem I mean (MI browser) thanks, how can I give a  true sign to you?

Comment: I can put my answer into an answer and you can accept it. I'm not sure which of my suggestions was correct though, let me know (so we don't mislead others that may land here in future).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I could find what's wrong with my code and miss understanding about how to work with cookies** the first problem is I must add another function to remember the browser yes I did something like that but I was changing the mode after refreshing it was because I had had change mode function inside the onload function... the second mistake was I thought that the cookies can be updated if we **before the expiration date** but it does not so I removed the expiration date to be updated and set again...

you are free to use my script anywhere, thanks for helping....

the code:

```
window.onload = function (){
  rememberMode();
}

function setCookie(cname,cvalue) {
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue;
  }
  
  function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
  
  function rememberMode() {
    var user=getCookie("user");
    if (user != "") {
      if(user == "dark"){
        dark();
      }else if(user == "light"){
        light();
      }
    } else {
          setCookie("user", "light");
          light();
        }
    }

  function changeMode() {
    var user=getCookie("user");
    if(user == "light"){
      dark();
      setCookie("user", "dark");
    }else if(user == "dark"){
      light();
      setCookie("user", "light");
    }
  }

function dark() {
    document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#171717";
    document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "#F1F1F1";
    document.getElementById("imod").src = "https://kurddoblaj.com/sun.gif";
    document.getElementById("search-box").style.backgroundColor = "#2A2A2A";
    document.getElementById("search").style.backgroundColor = "#2A2A2A";
    document.getElementById("search").style.color = "white";
    document.getElementById("z").style.color = "#595959";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#171717";
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "#2A2A2A";
        elems[i].style.color = "#F1F1F1";
    }
}

function light() {
    document.getElementById("2").style.backgroundColor = "#E3E3E3";
    document.getElementById("h2").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("imod").src = "https://kurddoblaj.com/moon.gif";
    document.getElementById("search-box").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("search").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("search").style.color = "black";
    document.getElementById("z").style.color = "black";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#E3E3E3";
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('post');
    for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "white";
        elems[i].style.color = "black";
    }
}
```